# NodeJS retrieve multiple data from MongoDB and display on Jade(Pug)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have some MongoDB collections, and need to display them in my site, making it a dynamic page(it's the team members, if 1 is removed or added, it should refresh on the page)

my collections is like(**mongodb terminal**):

```
db.capitao.find() = { "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b67519404d41f9988524"), "nome" : "Renato", "email" : "example@gmail.c
om", "imagem" : "renato.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 1 }

db.chassi.find() = { 
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b69f19404d41f9988529"), "nome" : "Carlos", "email" : "example@ufrgs.br
", "imagem" : "possebon.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b69f19404d41f998852a"), "nome" : "Felipe", "email" : "example@gmai
l.com", "imagem" : "brunetto.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b69f19404d41f998852b"), "nome" : "Isabelle", "email" : "example@
gmail.com", "imagem" : "isabelle.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b69f19404d41f998852c"), "nome" : "Mateus Dandolini Pescador", "email" : "example@ufrgs.b
r", "imagem" : "pescador.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59a6b69f19404d41f998852d"), "nome" : "Marcelino Colla Junior", "email" : "junior_colla@hotmail.com",
 "imagem" : "marcelino.png", "curso" : "Engenharia Mecânica", "lider" : 0 }
```

my index.js(only trying to retrieve from "capitao" first):

```
router.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
   var resultArray = {
                      capitao : [],
                      chassi : []
                     };

    var db = req.db;

    //var collectionCapitao = db.collection('capitao').find();

    var collectionCapitao = db.get('capitao');

    //var chassi = db.collection('chassi').find();

    collectionCapitao.find({},{},function(e,docs){
        res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: collectionCapitao
        });
    });
});
```

and my index.jade:

```
            .row
                each membro, i in capitao
                    .col-sm-4
                        .team-member
                            img.mx-auto.rounded-circle(src='/img/team/#{membro.imagem}', alt='#{membro.nome}')
                            h4 membro.nome
                            p.text-muted membro.curso
                            ul.list-inline.social-buttons
                                li.list-inline-item
                                    a(href="mailto:#{membro.email}")
                                        i.fa.fa-envelope
```

my problems:

- All properties return undefined in jade(SOLVED)
- "capitao" only has 1 record, but it generates 31 records in Jade(SOLVED)
- **how to get the MULTIPLE collections in the index.js and send them do Jade?**

Comment: You shouldn't publish Carlos's, Felipe's and Isabelle's email addresses like that.

Comment: It should be `res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: docs
        });`, not `capitao: collectionCapitao`

Comment: fixed, @JeremyThille

Comment: thanks @JeremyThille , it's displaying now..
but how to get from the other collections and render 1 time only?

Comment: That's much trickier. You need to make multiple calls, all asynchronous, and wait for the results of all these calls, then pass all these results to your template. Personally I would do this using the `AsyncJS` module.

Comment: I'll try that, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just rewritten the solution you have posted (glad it works :) because you repeat yourself a LOT (10 times the same function!)

So here's the DRY version (Don't Repeat Yourself).
Disclaimer : this is untested code!

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    const db = req.db;
    const async = require("async")

    const names = ['capitao','aerodinamica','chassi','controles','drivetrain','eletronica','gestao','marketing','powertrain','suspensao']

    const collections = names.map(name => db.get(name) )

    const functions = collections.map(collection => {
        return done => collection.find( {}, done )
    })

    async.series( functions, (err, results) => {
        // "results" is now an array containing [ docs1, docs2, .. ]
        res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: results[0],
            aerodinamica: results[1],
            chassi: results[2],
            controles: results[3],
            drivetrain: results[4],
            eletronica: results[5],
            gestao: results[6],
            marketing: results[7],
            powertrain: results[8],
            suspensao: results[9]
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot @Jeremy Thille , I'm actually new to Javascript/NodeJS..it's interesting to know that we can do the same thing like this, I'll put this on my project :D, I'll have other collections to access to, so it will really come in hand :D (and the code works ^^)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to make multiple calls to your database and wait for all the results, then pass all these results together to your template. Here's how to do it with AsyncJS :

```
const async = require("async")

async.series([
    done => collectionCapitao.find({}, done),
    done => collectionChassi.find({}, done)
], (err, results) => {
    // "results" is now an array containing [ docs1, docs2 ]
    res.render('index', {
        env: env,
        capitao: results[0],
        chassi : results[1]
    });
})
```

Since this code is quite minimal and concise, here's a slightly more detailed version so you understand better what's going on :

```
const getCapitao = done => {
     collectionCapitao.find({}, (err,docs) => {
          done(err, docs)
     })
}

const getChassi = done => {
     collectionChassi.find({}, (err,docs) => {
          done(err, docs)
     })
}

async.series([
    done => getCapitao(done),
    done => getChassi(done)
], ...... // get both results here
```

Comment: It works @Jeremy Thille, but sometimes I'm getting some errors that won't load the page..(node:5196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Callback was already
 called.
(node:5196) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
 that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

here's the code now, solved

```
router.get('/', function(req, res,next) {

    var db = req.db;


    var collectionCapitao = db.get('capitao');
    var collectionAerodinamica = db.get('aerodinamica');
    var collectionChassi = db.get('chassi');
    var collectionControles = db.get('controles');
    var collectionDrivetrain = db.get('drivetrain');
    var collectionEletronica = db.get('eletronica');
    var collectionGestao = db.get('gestao');
    var collectionMarketing = db.get('marketing');
    var collectionPowertrain = db.get('powertrain');
    var collectionSuspensao = db.get('suspensao');


    const async = require("async")

    const getCapitao = done => {
         collectionCapitao.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getAerodinamica = done => {
         collectionAerodinamica.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getChassi = done => {
         collectionChassi.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getControles = done => {
         collectionControles.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getDrivetrain = done => {
         collectionDrivetrain.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getEletronica = done => {
         collectionEletronica.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getGestao = done => {
         collectionGestao.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getMarketing = done => {
         collectionMarketing.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getPowertrain = done => {
         collectionPowertrain.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    const getSuspensao = done => {
         collectionSuspensao.find({}, (err,docs) => {
              done(err, docs)
         })
    }

    async.series([
        done => getCapitao(done),
        done => getAerodinamica(done),
        done => getChassi(done),
        done => getControles(done),
        done => getDrivetrain(done),
        done => getEletronica(done),
        done => getGestao(done),
        done => getMarketing(done),
        done => getPowertrain(done),
        done => getSuspensao(done),
    ], (err, results) => {
        // "results" is now an array containing [ docs1, docs2, .. ]
        res.render('index', {
            env: env,
            capitao: results[0],
            aerodinamica : results[1],
            chassi : results[2],
            controles : results[3],
            drivetrain : results[4], 
            eletronica : results[5],
            gestao : results[6],
            marketing : results[7], 
            powertrain : results[8],
            suspensao : results[9]
        });
    })
});
```